# What does this formula do?

Tags: excel

I am trying to understand this Excel formula, and understand IF statments, but not the structure of this one. What does the AND do?

```
=IF(AND(C8>59,C8<65),5%,
    IF(AND(C8>64,C8<70),5.5%,
        IF(AND(C8>69,C8<75),6%,
            IF(AND(C8>74,C8<80),6.5%,
                IF(AND(C8>79,C8<85),7%,
                    IF(AND(C8>84,C8<90),7.5%,
                        IF(AND(C8>89,C8<250),8%)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)*D8
```

Comment: You've heard what it does. What you, or somebody, should consider is replacing it with a table and VLOOKUP formula. :) That would be more maintainable when the rates change at some point.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, you can only nest IF statements 7 deep in Excel, a limitation that you won't run into with VLOOKUP.

Comment: Agreed that lookup or vlookup would be better - the limitation of 7 nested functions applies to Excel 2003 or earlier, later versions allow up to 64 but I wouldn't recommend going anywhere near that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND` function takes two boolean inputs and returns `TRUE` if they are both true.

The entire formula looks at the value of cell `C8` and returns the following:

5% if `C8` is between 59 and 65,

5.5% if `C8` is between 64 and 70,

6% if `C8` is between 69 and 75... et cetera.

Oh, and that is multiplied by whatever is found in cell `D8`

Answer (score 2):

It's (almost) equivalent to:

```
60  64  0.05
65  69  0.055
70  74  0.06
75  79  0.065
80  84  0.07
85  89  0.075
90      0.08

=VLOOKUP(C8,$A$1:$C$7,3,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AND()` function means that "all parameters must be true" for the function to evaluate to true. Thus, your first line, `=IF(AND(C8>59,C8<65),5%,...` means "if `C8` is between 69 and 65, return 5%. otherwise, go on to next line." Because excel `IF` statements have the structure `IF(conditional, true result, false result)`, if the statement on each line in your equation is not true, the the evaluation continues to the next line. Otherwise, it stops and returns the percentage on that line.

Answer (score 0):

The AND allows you to check a boolean condition on more than one statement.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267982

Answer (score 0):

Excel's AND takes 2 or more arguments that all must evaluate to true for the end result to be true.  In this case cell C8 is compared with 2 values to create a "between" like construction.

Rewritten in some kind of pseudocode this is what it could look like:

```
if ((C8>59) and (C8<65)) then 
    // meaning, for all values between 60 and 64, return 5%
    returnvalue = 5%
else
    if ((C8>64) and (C8<70)) then 
        // meaning, for all values between 65 and 70, return 5.5%
        returnvalue = 5.5%
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Easy reading is ..

IF C8>59 and C8<65 The result is **D8 * 5%** 
IF C8>64 and C8<70 The result is **D8 * 5.5%** 
IF C8>69 and C8<75 The result is **D8 * 6%** 
IF C8>74 and C8<80 The result is **D8 * 6.5%** 
IF C8>79 and C8<85 The result is **D8 * 7%** 
IF C8>84 and C8<90 The result is **D8 * 7.5%** 
IF C8>89 and C8<250 The result is **D8 * 8%**

So if your **C8 is 66** and **D8 is 5** then the result is **5 * 0.55 = 2.75**